# Prevent mediaplayer from calling onCompletionListener

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to play music when an user selects a song from the `listview`.

```
 if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } else {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
```

`mMediaPlayer.reset();` is calling the `onCompletionListener`. In my `oncompletionListener`, I'm playing the next song and hence instead of playing the selected song, it plays the next song in the `listview`. Is there by any ways I can prevent calling `onCompletionListener` and play only the song that's selected from `listview`?

Comment: Hi. Maybe you can add a boolean flag (isMediaPlayerReset) and set it to true when the player is manually reset and check it on the onCompletionListener.

Comment: okay when should i be setting the isMediaPlayerReset to true and false? and how should I handle the lifecycle? any hint or gist will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
 boolean isMediaPlayerReset = false;
 MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;



    //on list item click
    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        isMediaPlayerReset = true;
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/path");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(isMediaPlayerReset){
                isMediaPlayerReset = false;
                return;
            }
            //play next song
        }
    });
```